# Deploy Angular5 app to Tomcat with environment.{{ENV}}.ts

Tags: javascript, angular, tomcat, ng-build

I have an angular app, with environment configs which helps it to connect to different API endpoints based on the configuration.

`ng build --prod --environment={{ENV}}` is how is build the app.

I copy the artifacts to the folder where tomcat hosts from. However, the local env is always picked out.

`ng serve --env={{ENV}}` would work, but how do i do the same using Tomcat?

Thanks,
Pratik

Comment: try this: ng build --prod --env={{ENV}}

Comment: @Pratik is your problem resolved? I am running into same issue. Could you please share what have worked for you.

Comment: @MSV, I was able to work around it. Sharing that.

Comment: @MSV - Let me know if it solves the issue.

Comment: @Pratik how do you configure Tomcat to set the config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the Angular CLI version.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7643

I currently have my CLI updated to

```
"@angular/cli": "1.6.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0"
```

If you do `ng build --prod`, it does pick up the `environment-prod.ts` now.